# Prevent validation rules while converting lead

Tags: validation-rule

Is it good practice to bypass the validation rules or triggers while conversion of the Leads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your organization's business processes. If you have rules or triggers deal directly with conversion, then you should enable the feature. If you don't have any rules that you care to enforce during conversion, you can turn it off so conversions will be faster.